# Access local owncloud on ipad

Tags: networking, ipad, owncloud

ive just installed owncloud and made a "local" on my linux machine. i am trying to connect my ipad which is on the same network to it but i do not know what the server adress is?

i cannot seem to find alot of documentation on the subject so i was hoping someone here would be able to help me out?

The server is on my local machine as localhost/owncloud

Is that the adress i need to use?

because if so it says that it cannot find the server

Comment: nop. local host will point your local machine. check @Aline answer. ifconfig, will list all your Netcards.

Answer (score 0):

localhost is just name for your local host and it translates to 127.0.0.1 IP adress, which your computer identifies as itself.
You need to get your local IP address on your linux machine with this command

```
ifconfig
```

then on your ipad use that address. For example - 192.168.1.2/owncloud